# missing function of library in linker rust - littlefs

Tags: rust

I am writing a static library that has some dependencies names [littlefs2](https://docs.rs/littlefs2/0.3.2/littlefs2/) , littlefs2-sys. the code compiles but when I use the library in my codes the linker misses the functions in littlefs-sys.

the output is

```
../../target/armv5te-none-eabi/release/librustify.a(rustify-ca33b219841f9e74.rustify.a123863a-cgu.0.rcgu.o): In function `proc_main_task':
rustify.a123863a-cgu.0:(.text.proc_main_task+0x3f8): undefined reference to `lfs_format'
../../target/armv5te-none-eabi/release/librustify.a(rustify-ca33b219841f9e74.rustify.a123863a-cgu.0.rcgu.o): In function `littlefs2::fs::Filesystem$LT$Storage$GT$::mount::hd38e2070178f9048':
rustify.a123863a-cgu.0:(.text._ZN9littlefs22fs25Filesystem$LT$Storage$GT$5mount17hd38e2070178f9048E+0x34): undefined reference to `lfs_mount'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Edit:  the library was working previously but I omitted it for month. recently I could not build it anymore . Many changes added to my project but nothing relevent to this library. I am suspiciouse to rust new changes because the nightly version of rust act wierd some times.

Comment: Is it the crate littlefs or littlefs2 ?

Comment: It is littlef2.

Comment: from the readme, It seems like [littlefs-sys](https://github.com/brandonedens/rust-littlefs) should be used with [littlefs crate](https://crates.io/crates/littlefs), not [littelfs2 crate](https://crates.io/crates/littlefs2). For littlefs2, you need [littlefs2-sys](https://crates.io/crates/littlefs2-sys). Maybe it's the cause of your error or just a another typo.

Comment: Tnx for your attention. I added some changes that may help. As I mentioned there the library worked fine but recently this error shows up.